# Dynamic Server-Side Playlists in Silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight, server-side, playlists

I'm trying to generate dynamic video playlists for Silverlight, to be able enable playback from several diffent video files.
E.g. I need to tell Silverlight to play 10 seconds of video 1, starting at timecode 1 minute 15 seconds and then seamlessly change to play 60 seconds of video 2 starting at timecode 5 minutes 2 seconds.
It has to playback as if it were one single video, ie. no buffering inbetween vidoes.

And this needs to happen on-the-fly, meaning javascript will build the playlist and/or ask the server to build the playlist.

I was looking into the server side playlists (wsx files) but it seems they cannot be created on-the-fly as is necessary.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer was, as always, buried deep inside MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd893516(VS.85).aspx